# Why must a short exact sequence of Kahler Differentials exist.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, exact-sequence

On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_differential) for Kahler Differentials, under examples and basic facts - it is said that given two ring homomorphisms:
$R \rightarrow S \rightarrow T$, there is a short exact sequence $\Omega_{S/R}\otimes_ST \rightarrow \Omega_{T/R} \rightarrow \Omega_{T/S} \rightarrow 0.$  Can someone give me any direction as to why such a sequence must exist?

Comment: Did you look up a book, say Matsumura's Commutative Algebra?

Comment: No, but that sounds like a good place to start.  I'll follow up here or with a new question if I can't make sense of it.